Problema al iniciar la cámara con OpenCV en una app Android con Jetpack Compose
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de Android usando Jetpack Compose y OpenCV para procesar video en tiempo real. He configurado todo correctamente y OpenCV se carga sin problemas, pero la cámara no se inicia y solo se muestra el fondo con el mensaje "Hello Android".
He implementado la cámara usando JavaCamera2View de OpenCV y la he integrado en mi actividad principal de la siguiente manera:
***AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        JavaCamera2View(context, -1).apply {
            setCvCameraViewListener(this@MainActivity)
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            visibility = android.view.View.VISIBLE
        }
    },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
)***

Los permisos de la cámara están correctamente solicitados y concedidos, como confirmo mediante logging y comprobaciones en tiempo de ejecución. Sin embargo, a pesar de que los permisos son concedidos y la librería OpenCV se carga correctamente, la cámara no muestra la vista previa, solo se ve el fondo definido en Compose.
***override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if (requestCode == 1 && grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        cameraView?.enableView()
        cameraView?.visibility = android.view.View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Camera permission not granted")
    }
}***

Logs de error:
OpenCV se carga sin problemas.
No hay errores específicos en los logs que indiquen un fallo al acceder a la cámara.
¿Hay algún paso adicional que deba considerar para la inicialización de la cámara con JavaCamera2View en Jetpack Compose?
¿Podría haber alguna configuración adicional en Android que esté impidiendo que la cámara inicie correctamente?
Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia será muy apreciada. ¡Gracias de antemano!
